# Using Entity Framework to copy entities between databases

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-4

Having 2 separate databases with the same schema, I need to copy entities (records) from one database to another using Entity Framework 4.

I'm creating 2 Contexts, but I'm getting the following error when I add one entity to the second Context:

```
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
```

I know I can avoid that error if i use the Detach method, but in that case the related entities are lost!

Sample code:

```
        var cx = new MyEntities();

        //eager load related tables
        var allEntities = from x in cx.Reservation.Include("Detail.MoreDetail")
                  select x;

        // new instance of context but connected to a second database
        var cx2 = new MyEntities( new ConnectionString...);
        foreach (var e in allEntities)
        {
            //cx.Detach(reservation);  // can't detach, or related entities will be lost
            cx2.AddToReservation(reservation);  // error happens here!
            cx2.SaveChanges();                
        }
```

How can I perform such operation?
Alternatively, how can I detach the entity without losing the related entities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For once the error message is helpful - entities can only belong to one context at a time.  To do what you're wanting you'll need to `Detatch` each entity from the first context before adding it to the second.

Like you said, this will kill related entities.  Unfortunately you'll have to deal with this (annoying) aspect of `Detach`.

Answer (score 6):

For future reference, the following article helped me:

[Cloning the Entity object and all related children using the Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CloningLINQ2Entities.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A good solution which can save time:
http://lorifpeterson.com/?p=75

> **Disable EF Tracking**
>
> When you are retrieving an entity or entities from a dataset, you can
> tell Entity Framework not to track any of the changes that you are
> making to that object and then add that entity as a new entity to the
> dataset.  With using .AsNoTracking, the context doesn’t know anything
> about the existing entity.
>
> ```
> var entity = context.MyDataSet
>                     .AsNoTracking()
>                     .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1);
>
> context.MyDataSet.Add(entity);
> context.SaveChanges();  
>
> You can also include child entities as well
>
> var entity = context.MyDataSet
>                     .AsNoTracking()
>                     .Including(ds => ds.MyChildEntities)
>                     .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1);
>
> context.MyDataSet.Add(entity);
> context.SaveChanges();  // creates a new object graph in the database
> ```
>
> **EF Copying Current Values**
>
> Using this technique, you can get the current values from an existing
> entity object and set the values to your newly created entity object.
>
> ```
> var originalEntity = context.MyDataSet
>                             .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1);
>
> var entity = new MyDataSetEntity();
> context.MyDataSet.Add(entity);  //Create and add new entity object to context before setting its values
>
> var originalEntityValues = Context.Entry(originalEntity).CurrentValues;
> Context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(originalEntityValues); 
> //Copy values from original entity to new entity
>
> entity.MyProperty1 = "Changed value"; // make any changes to the new entity
> entity.MyProperty2 = "Another changed value";
>
> context.SaveChanges();
> ```